# Get user picture from database on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, image, forms

I want to get the users profile picture from the database and show it as a view in iPhone.

There is a list with users that has been registered in the database and I do get this user as a variable: username. And when you click on one of the names it gets stored in the variable. I want to take that username, and ask the server for his/her profile picture and then load it.

So my php file is all set up, its simple. It takes the username and `SELECT user_picture WHERE $username='username'`

and then it echo´s out the url to users picture.

What do I need to do, to get this to be a working thing. Ask for profile picture -> read server output -> load image

Hope this isnt to complicated and written by me.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need when you fetch the user's picture name then reference it's name which stored in your local machine

```
$user_picture = "Select pictureName from user where username = 'what you want'";
```

use your fetched name to reference in you img tag

```
"<img src=". <?php $user_picture ?> . ' alt="alt" height="42" width="42">'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. But this is for iPhone, maybe should have been more clear on that part. But nothing wrong with your codes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use store the username or userid into your session. And then do that query what you want.

Actually i did not get you question. What you want to do actually with the user. If you want to get Pictures/profile info for the specific user then use the following query. Hope the answer.

If this is not clear please paste a code.

```
    $sql = "Select user_picture from YOUR_USER_TABLE where username='username'"
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
    echo($result['user_picture']);
or you can use this in html img Tag like this.

<img src="<?php echo($result['user_picture']); ?>" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. But this is for iPhone, maybe should have been more clear on that part. But nothing wrong with your codes ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Ask for profile picture -> read server output -> load image,
```

In this process, use JSON (or your desired) to read the response from web-service, which returns image URL.

To load image into UIImageView from web-service use below:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath1];//imagePath1 is returned by web-service
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             imgview.image=img;
         });
    });
```

It will load image to imgView(UIImageView) asynchronously.  Add this UIImageView as a subview to desired view to show as a separate view.